# why does ~True not work in pandas dataframe conditional

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use switches to turn on and off conditionals in a pandas dataframe.  The switches are just boolean variables that will be True or False.  The problem is that ~True does not evaluate the same as False as I expected it to.  Why does this not work?

```
>>> dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [3, 4, 5, 6], 'col2': [6, 5, 4, 3]})
>>> dataframe
   col1  col2
0     3     6
1     4     5
2     5     4
3     6     3
>>> dataframe.loc[dataframe.col1 <= dataframe.col2]
   col1  col2
0     3     6
1     4     5
>>> dataframe.loc[(True) | (dataframe.col1 <= dataframe.col2)]
   col1  col2
0     3     6
1     4     5
2     5     4
3     6     3
>>> dataframe.loc[(False) | (dataframe.col1 <= dataframe.col2)]
   col1  col2
0     3     6
1     4     5
>>> dataframe.loc[(~True) | (dataframe.col1 <= dataframe.col2)]
   col1  col2
0     3     6
1     4     5
2     5     4
3     6     3
>>> dataframe.loc[(~(True)) | (dataframe.col1 <= dataframe.col2)]
   col1  col2
0     3     6
1     4     5
2     5     4
3     6     3
>>>

>>> dataframe  = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col2': [True, False, False, True]})
>>> dataframe
   col1   col2
0     1   True
1     2  False
2     3  False
3     4   True
>>> dataframe.loc[dataframe.col2]
   col1  col2
0     1  True
3     4  True
>>> dataframe.loc[not dataframe.col2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1537, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
>>> dataframe.loc[dataframe.col2 == False]
   col1   col2
1     2  False
2     3  False
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Pandas. Look at what `~True` on its own does.

Comment: Pandas and NumPy implement their own `~` handling for their own types, but `~` on a plain built-in `bool` doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: use `not True` to invert True

Comment: I got trapped into thinking everything in a pandas conditional had to use pandas conditional operators.  Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pandas operator behavior (implemented from Numpy).

`True` is not a pandas object. Instead it's a boolean. So obviously, the `~` operator isn't meant to reverse booleans, only in Pandas.

As you can see:

```
>>> ~True
-2
>>>
```

It gives `-2`, which is the regular `__invert__` magic method behavior.

Therefore:

```
>>> bool(-2)
True
>>>
```

Gives `True`.

Don't mix up Pandas and Python behavior, Pandas implements it's on `__invert__` usage, example:

```
>>> ~pd.Series([True])
0    False
dtype: bool
>>>
```

As you can see, in pandas (also Numpy), it inverts the booleans. Therefor if you write:

```
>>> dataframe.loc[~pd.Series([True]).any() | (dataframe.col1 <= dataframe.col2)]
   col1  col2
0     3     6
1     4     5
>>>
```

You can clearly see that it behaves equivalently as `False`.

The best way here is with `not`:

```
>>> dataframe.loc[(not True) | (dataframe.col1 <= dataframe.col2)]
   col1  col2
0     3     6
1     4     5
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think '~' is not what you want, maybe you want to use 'not':

```
>>> dataframe.loc[(not True) | (dataframe.col1 <= dataframe.col2)]
   col1  col2
0     3     6
1     4     5
```